# PILLOW - Write list images in PDF using PIL and and compressed in PNG

Tags: python, image, pdf, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to save a list of images in a PDF :

> frames[0].save(buff, format='PDF', save_all=True,
> append_images=frames[1:])

But when I'm doing like that, it seems that the images are compressed in JPEG inside the PDF. Is it possible to compress as PNG images?

Thanks for help

Comment: Not sure, if I understand this correctly, but if the pictures are encoded as JPG in the PDF, conversion to PNG has a number of disadvantes: You keep the JPG artifacts and  get the worse compression (PNG is lossless).

Comment: For example I have 4 images loaded with PIL. I save these 4 images as PNG, and I make the PDF with the PIL images. And what I see is that the PDF use really less memory than all PNG, and seems because the compression is in JPEG. The only thing I would like is to have the same quality with my images saved in PNG ? Sorry for my english ^^

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read a PDF or TIFF, then I save every image of the PDF using newImg1.save("img1.png","PNG"). I need as ouput a PDF with a size limit, so I add my images in a list and when it's bigger than my size limit I save the PDF using frames[0].save(buff, format='PDF', save_all=True, append_images=frames[1:]). But so the memory size I calculate is based on the saved PNG, and when I save the PDF it seems that JPEG is using because the size is smaller and the quality worse..